# "Illegal variable name" error when running "docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)"

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko, csh

I am trying to issue command `docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)` over ssh, using Python's paramiko package

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh_client.exec_command('docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)');
print stderr.readlines()
```

I get an error `Illegal variable name`. I tried putting in double quote (""), escape the $, (, ) ... but running out of ideas

Comment: Where is the error from?

Comment: dont know the reason you use csh but take a look at [csh-why-not](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're using [csh](/questions/tagged/csh) as the login shell on the ssh server. Csh does not support `$(...)` so try

```
ssh_client.exec_command('docker stop `docker ps -a -q` ');
```

---

Csh example:

```
# echo $(echo foo)
Illegal variable name.
#
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a university machine, so got the default shell to changed to bash. As expected, my original command runs fine as well :-)